# asyncio run task in jupyter notebook with retries upon failure

Tags: python, python-asyncio, dask

I would like to run a script.py file from a jupyter notebook:

```py
%run script.py
```

My task is to run a map-reduce on partitions of data on a dask cluster, asynchronously. The workers sometimes (like 5% of cases) randomly crash, due to a connection error, that we did not figure out yet, what is the reason for it. So, for now, I wanted to write a small loop around my async loop call that handles retrying up to n_tries_max times upon failure. The code in script.py looks like this:

```py
# small wrapper for async stuff
async def my_func(args):
    await ...

# try running the function with retries on failure
n_tries_max = 3
n_try = 1
while n_try<=n_tries_max:
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        task = loop.create_task(my_func(args))
        asyncio.wait_for(task,timeout=None)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        n_try += 1
        continue
    break
```

This works within jupyter notebook, however, I get a warning at the beginning:

```py
/mt/users/jc/scripts/run_parallel_comp.py:62: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'wait_for' was never awaited
  asyncio.wait_for(task,timeout=None)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

After the warning, the script keeps running and finishes correctly though. Just wanted to ask for the cause of this warning?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason to not use the dask-provided functions? (re: "run a map-reduce on partitions of data on a dask cluster")

Comment: this is basically what is done inside my_func already. i just need this wrapper that executes my_func and retries it whenever my_func fails (or more exactly, when one of the tasks on the workers that are created by my_func fails)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should differentiate the meaning of  async/await in Javascript and Python.

- When you call an awaitable function, you create a new coroutine object in Python.
- `asyncio.create_task` returns coroutine object to be waited using `await` keyword.

You should probably call this coroutine object using `await` keyword.

```
# small wrapper for async stuff
async def my_func(args):
    await ...

# try running the function with retries on failure
n_tries_max = 3
n_try = 1
while n_try<=n_tries_max:
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        task = loop.create_task(my_func(args))
        await task
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        n_try += 1
        continue
    break
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! this would give me an await outside function error, though. i dont understand how to fix it

Comment: `
import asyncio
import time
async def lazy(secs):
    await asyncio.sleep(secs)
    print('dddd')

async def my_func():
    await lazy(3)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = loop.create_task(my_func())
await task
`

I tried with this code and working well.

Comment: so, this would raise an error outside jupyter notebooks, cause the await would be outside an async function. in the end, managed to find the solution by putting the while loop inside the wrapper function and then just calling `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        task = loop.create_task(my_func(args))` outside the func